# Cannot set Suppression Period Length to 0 days

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration, contactbuilder

I want to test some assumptions in deleting contacts, and it seems as though I'm able to set the suppression period length to any amount of days other than 0. As soon as I attempt to set it to 0 it saves it as 30 days.  What would be preventing this? We do have the Multi Org Connector installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest „nothing“. There are multiple areas where a 0 value can be saved but it shows the old value which was set before saving to zero or a default value.

One of another area where this is true is the recommendation item count in recommendations. When you set it to zero it is zero but shows 3.

I deleted with a suppression state of zero but I also had a suppression period of 30 when I set to zero. It’s definitely a Ui bug which you could tell Salesforce Support.

Just try deletion with a 0 suppression days configuration with one or two fake contacts and watch how they behave. Do the same with 1 day with other contacts and watch how the suppression period behaves. If it is not like you expected it to behave raise a support ticket.

Comment: You're absolutely right - even though it shows 30 days in the suppression period it is actually processing as 0. I'm going to report this as a UI bug.

Comment: Bug noted here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ATHRQA4&title=contacts-delete-settings-will-not-retain-0-days